# Mac true folder sync

Tags: mac, networking, osx-snow-leopard, backup, sync

I'm looking for a free solution to sync 2 folders together with a true sync. Meaning you delete a file in either place, and it updates that in the other folder. Not a backup from one to the other type like most software solutions have.

Is there a free solution out there for this?

I tried rSync but that doesn't seem to allow for true syncing.

I'm on Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to go cross-platform, try [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).  It works at the command line, and does a very good job.

Comment: does this feature a nice GUI? I prefer not to use command line

Comment: You can use it either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what Git is, I wouldn't recommend it for this purpose.

A program like ChronoSync might be more in-line with what you're looking for.

**UPDATE**

Another program that might help out is called [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html).

Comment: is there a free equivalency?

Comment: Actually, yes. I've used ChronoSync before, but I just remembered that SuperDuper is free for "basic" features, would at least get you started. See UPDATE above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this via Git. It does much more as it remembers all the history and thus is also more complex to use but you could write simple shortcut scripts which do just the syncing. If you want to safe space and not safe the full history (but only the last 10 changes or so), you can do that also with Git.

Comment: how do I get started with this? i don't know what Git is, sorry.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/ http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html I'm doing it via Terminal. You need some background knowledge or need to learn a few commands to use it. I don't know if there are easy to use GUIs for that (because I feel more comfortable in the console).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) on a [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) schedule if you're not married to using a GUI for it.  otherwise, I'd suggest going with one of the other answers.  This is a little bit of initial set up as you get it running, but then it will be fairly stable after that.  Basic unix tools don't generally change drastically too often.